# Wiring a BJT differential amplifier in a circuit

Tags: bjt, differential, comparator

I need to switch a **12V relay** when an input signal passes a certain voltage threshold. I use this popular **BJT amplifier**:
[image]

**In my case:**

1. `VCC` = 5V
2. `RC1` = `RC2` = 2.2k
3. `RE` = 1k
4. `Q1` = `Q2` = BC547
5. `VIN1` and `VIN2` are `DC voltages` set by potentiometers.

The ideea is that one input(with voktages ranging from 0-5v) will be compared to the second(same range). Based on which is bigger  a relay will be opened or closed.
The current circuit's precision is good enough with 0.04V threshold before a big enough voltage appears on the outputs.

At this moment approximately `1.8V` are between `VO1` and `VO2` which is perfect. The only problem is that this voltage is not referenced to ground. This means I can't use a transistor with the base and emitter connected to the two outputs and the collector to the `12v rail`. One solution would be to have an isolated source between the collector and emitter of this transistor for powering the relay but this it's not convenient.

Another solution which I tested was to connect the two outputs to a `optocoupler` which then provided power for a `Darlington transistor` and finally for the relay and `12V`.

The reality is that I couldn't find a circuit that used such an amplifier so I don't know how I should use it.

**NOTE:** I don't have any `opamp` laying around just `BJTs`, `mosfets` , `diodes` and `resistors`.

Comment: Rather than talking a lot about the problems you are having with your schematic here, why don't you spend more time talking about what exactly you want to achieve. I've got some clues, already. You are driving a relay, for example. But no where near enough details. What's your source? What kind of hysteresis do you need? What voltage sources are readily accessible to a circuit you want to build? How much precision do you need in the thresholds? What operating temperature range do you expect? Etc.

Comment: what's the range of Vin1 and Vin2 ? by the way, you will need a hysteresis mechanism when implementing an analog comparator, otherwise the output might be uncertain and bouncing when the input voltage's value is close to the reference voltage.

Comment: @Hamid I noticed on a simulation that it oscillates a little when the two voltages are equal. I want the final connected relay to be stable. Would a capacitor solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relay is on when VG1-VG2 > 30mV.

[image: relay1]

[image]

**EDIT:**

NPN only version:
The relay is on when VG2-VG1 > 20mV.

[image: relaynpn]

[image: relaynpn2]

Comment: Could this work with NPN only?

Comment: @sergiu reznicencu It has become a bit complicated but works with NPN transistors. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Look at the circuit from "M lab"

Following up on the circuit of M lab, let us add ONE TRANSISTOR, and you will have a very useful OUTPUT CURRENT referenced to VCC.

The circuit OUTPUT, as is, running at +5 volts VCC, will provide about 0.5mA pulling up, or 0.5mA pulling down.

Let use boost that.

Simply add a 2N3906 PNP, emitter to VCC, and base to OUTPUT.

The new PNP's collector is now your output current.

This new transistor can provide up to  BETA * 0.5mA = 50 milliamp.

If you want to switch amps, then use a large bipolar NPN, emitter grounded, base to this new PNP, 1K resistor in parallel across the NPN emitter_base, and probably a high_current clamp diode from collector to ground so you can drive a relay. Have the clamp diode oriented with cathode (the line on the diode) to collector.

Comment: There's no single output. The voltge difference is between VO1 and VO2. "Base to output" which one?

Comment: The node labelled 'output' on the circuit from @M lab

Comment: Oh. I see it now

Answer (score 0):

I found this schematic  many year ago. It called discrete op-amp. also ack like normal opamp. the minimum output voltage is about 1.4V and maximum should be Vcc-0.7 due to Vbe of bjt.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ovvR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same result using only NPN transistors for Q6 and Q5?

Comment: @sergiureznicencu No, it need  contruct positive current mirror which only possible using PNP.